# Scheduler for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks

I want to run some of my apps code every night in some sort of task or scheduler. Is there any build in functionality in the framework? If not, whats an easy 3rd party framework to get scheduling?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use Window's Scheduling functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a console application and run it as a scheduled task.  Alternatively you could look at using Quartz.Net which is a port of the Java Quartz, a framework for scheduling jobs.

Either way your finished product will likely be a console application that is scheduled to run with scheduled tasks, or a class library as a Windows Service.  ASP.NET its self won't do the scheduling.

Answer (score -3):

If you can, you could use IIS 7.5 Application Warm-Up Module : http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2009/10/14/now-available-the-iis-7-5-application-warm-up-module.aspx

Comment: Don't know how this allows him to schedule stuff to happen each night.